# Scroll to top of a lightbox div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a jQueryUI dialog box with content exceeding the default height (so it scrolls within the dialog box), and at the bottom there is a submit button. I am using ajaxstart to show a loading screen but due to the dialog scrolling, you do not see the loading div, except if I click on the button and scroll manually to the top.

I want to be able to scroll to the top of the div within the dialog box on a click event. I have the following code which I tried (but no success):

```
#loading {
z-index: 200;
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000000;

/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
/* ...but not required as filter works too */
/* should come BEFORE filter */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
/* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=70);

/* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
-moz-opacity:0.5;

/* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Modern!
/* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
/* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
opacity: 0.5;
 }

 // jQuery Script:
 $("input[name='docSubmit']").click(function() {
            var height = $("#attendeeManual").height();
            $("#loading").css("height",height);
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#attendeeManual').offset().top - 20}, 'slow');
        });
```

Comment: Capture the ID or the Class of the window that has the scrollbar. Then use `$('#thisWindow').scrollTop(0);` to scroll to the top of that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion by **Ohgodwhy**, a simple `$("#div").scrollTop(0)` takes you to the very top of the div. I have read that this can be animated, but for my purposes I only needed it to return to the top, nothing else :) Thank you!